# C++ unit-test project LoadLibrary fail with Ordinal Not Found error

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mfc, loadlibrary

I have a C++ unit-test project and i am using the `LoadLibraryEx` function to load a dll i created for my application but the `LoadLibraryEx` fail and return NULL and after it i called `GetLastError` function and the error is 182. i also noticed that in the output window after executing the line of the `LoadLibraryEx` an error appear `Exception thrown at 0x771718D6 (ntdll.dll) in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: 0xC0000138: Ordinal Not Found.`

Please note that when i run the application the library loads successfully and the loading only fails when loading from the unit-test.

Comment: set `ShowSnaps` (same as `LdrpDebugFlags`) in ntdll before call `LoadLibraryEx` and look for output

Comment: sorry, but where and how i can set the ShowSnaps

Comment: in debugger. set it manually, before call `LoadLibraryEx` which fail

Comment: this is `DWORD` value. set it to `0xffffffbf` yourself exactly before call `LoadLibraryEx`.

Comment: i didn't find such a flag or i don't know how to set it. is there a sample or example ?

Comment: i mean i should put in code or some configuration ? i am using visual studio

Comment: you need have `ntdll.pdb` symbols for `ntdll.dll` installed. can for example debug in *windbg* and set symbol file path for auto download symbols (`srv*c:\windows\symbols`). then set `ntdll!LdrpDebugFlags` to `0xFFFFFFBF` exactly before failed `LoadLibraryEx`

Comment: set bp on `LoadLibraryEx` which fail. when stop on bp - simply type in memory window [ntdll!LdrpDebugFlags](https://i.imgur.com/zdjDtBQ.png) and modify memory dword to `0xffffffbf`. then `F10` on `LoadLibraryEx` and view log

Comment: i cant debug tom windbg becuase i am running a test case from test explorer from VS and if i try to attach windbg to the proccess it tells me that i cant attach it because it's being debuged

Comment: you can debug in any debugger. VS debugger is ok too. all what you need - modify dword at address `ntdll!LdrpDebugFlags` to `0xFFFFFFBF` - are your VS load symbols for *ntdll.dll* - if yes - just do it. if no symbols - open any process with **same** bitness (32 or 64) in *windbg* - notepad (32 or 64 depend from your exe) for example. and look address (numeric value) of `ntdll!LdrpDebugFlags`. this address will be the same in all processes. of course in case your process is 32 on 64 windows (wow64 process). look this in 32bit ntdll

Comment: what this give you - verbose debug info - which exactly ordinal,  from which library is not found. all libraries load paths, etc. you need do this log (by set `ntdll!LdrpDebugFlags` to `0xFFFFFFBF`) just before call `LoadLibraryEx` in failed test. and in application which work well. and compare it. and you easy view different and why fail

Comment: thank you for your help, this is the message in output "the ordinal 345 could not be located in the dynamic link library comctl32.dll"

Comment: in which version of comctl32.dll ? may be in 5.81 ? when application which work well use 6.0+ version ? which is path for comctl32.dll ? simply paste/compare 2 logs - from fail app and from ok. may be you not use manifest in unit test for select 6+ version of comctl32

Comment: [`TaskDialogIndirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544(v=vs.85).aspx) - you import this function from *Comctl32.dll*. but it exist only in version 6. sure that in unit test you forget use in manifest correct version of *Comctl32.dll* and as result 5.82 version is loaded, where no `TaskDialogIndirect`

Comment: really you need have manifest in dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your dll is import [`TaskDialogIndirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544(v=vs.85).aspx) function from *Comctl32.dll*. but this function is exported only by **version 6** and later of *Comctl32.dll*. but for use this version must be active activation context where exist:

```
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' 
        name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' 
        version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*'   
        publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

otherwise will be loaded [*5.82 version*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298349(v=vs.85).aspx) of *ComCtl32.dll* which not export `TaskDialogIndirect` and dll fail to load.

which activation context will be active at dll load time ?

if dll have own manifest (`RT_MANIFEST`, `ISOLATIONAWARE_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID`) - activation context will be created based on dll manifest and it will be used during dll load. otherwise it undefined. this can be (faster of all) context created based on manifest from exe file, or another.

based on your error- i can say - your dll have not (`RT_MANIFEST`, `ISOLATIONAWARE_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID`) manifest resource. this is error. probably application which load your dll have own manifest, where declared version 6 of common controls, as result dll load ok. but unit test exe have no manifest at all, or no version 6 in manifest. as result old version of *comctl32.dll* is loaded and here not exported `TaskDialogIndirect`.

anyway dll must not depend from external context - where it loaded. for this it mandatory must have own manifest.

so create manifest for dll, which have `<dependency>` - `<dependentAssembly>` for `<assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' />` and include this manifest as resource:

```
ISOLATIONAWARE_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "manifest file name"
```

with this, when you dll will be load - always version 6+ of *comctl32.dll* will be used

---

how research errors like this ?

most effective way set `DWORD LdrpDebugFlags` from *ntdll.dll* (in xp - `BOOLEAN ShowSnaps` to `true`) to `0xFFFFFFBF` exactly before call to `LoadLibrary` in debugger. as result linker print verbose debug messages during dll load - and you exactly view where is process fail. also, in some hard case, be good also log success dll load too and compare this logs.

> the ordinal *345* could not be located in the dynamic link library
>   *comctl32.dll*

when we have ordinal instead name - run

`link.exe /dump /exports "<path>comctl32.lib" > comctl32.log`

and look log. and in log we can found:

```
345    TaskDialogIndirect
```

now look msdn Requirements section for [`TaskDialogIndirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544(v=vs.85).aspx) - when we view *Comctl32.dll* (**version 6**) - all became clear

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have added a manifest file name for the dll but not as resource, i added it in the same directory of the project and it reconized it but after adding the manifest the test case wont run and it fails with unspecified error

Comment: @AlaaL - manifest must be added only as resource in dll. as separate file this work only for exe. so add manifest exactly to dll

Comment: @AlaaL - and are you name manifest as `test.dll.2.manifest` where your dll name is `test.dll` ? and that test exe wont run after this say that you at first faster add manifest for exe instead, at second that manifest internal is probably wrong. so the best add `2 RT_MANIFEST filename` to dll rc file. and which manifest you exactly use ?

Comment: Thank you all for your help, i have added the manifest for the project who is using TaskDialogIndirect not for the test project and it worked

Comment: It turns out that it fails in test only and not in the appliction because the exe of the appliction has a manifest file which load the correct comctl32.dll

Comment: @AlaaL - the correct way - add manifest exactly to dll - the dll use version 6 - so and here must be manifest. dll in general must be independent from exe to where it loaded. it must correct work even if exe have no manifest. for this and need have manifest in dll exactly